# Document Set feature available in SharePoint Foundation 2010?

Tags: document-library, document-set

Document Set feature available in SharePoint Foundation 2010 please give any info this feature. This feature is available only sharePoint 2010 Server.

Answer (score 1):

No Document Set Feature is not available in SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Please refer to this [technet blog post on the feature](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vedant/archive/2010/04/21/using-the-document-set-feature-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1.aspx).